# Overriden class method throwing TypeError (missing 'self')

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I need to replace a method class wide, from what I found, this was the way to do it:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

def maximize_(self):
    # do things

Window.maximize = maximize_
```

Later when I call `Window.maximize()`, throws:

`TypeError: maximize_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

There is only ever 1 `Window` in a `kivy` application, so I just need to replace this function entirely.

Comment: You don't seem to have an instance of `Window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kivy `window` methods are static. Assuming you do not use the `self` parameter of `maximize_` within the function, I would remove the parameter.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

def maximize_():
    # do things

Window.maximize = maximize_
```

Comment: Yea that ended up working. However, where are the defined to be static?

Comment: Even the source code `__init__.py` has `def maximize(self)`; the `self` would imply a non-static method would it not?

Comment: What's returned as ```Window``` is not one class, but a collection of classes frameworked through several custom functions. I'm not sure how it works internally, but the final ```Window``` is meant to be used statically.